# Information within a custom directive not displaying properly in my angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi am currently trying to learn angular and have been stuck wish and issue for a little over two weeks. I am hoping someone may be able to shine some light on my situation. I have a block of code I am trying to pull out and put into a custom directive. I am working through the free course for angular from CodeSchool.com. I am trying to pull the paneled section containing the description, the specs, and the reviews and place them in their own pace so I can call a  directive from my index.html. Here is an example of my code working and when it breaks. It breaks when I attempt to remove the tabsController from app.js and place it into a directive. [Example Code](http://pastie.org/9739654) . Thank you for your time in advance,

Sincerely, Fred K

Comment: There are two very useful Chrome extensions you can use for debugging Angular: Batarang & ng-inspector

Comment: Yes batarang has been very helpful thank you for the tip. The issue I was having was that I had no server running so none of the ajax requests could retrieve their information. As soon as I ran it through express it behaved fine.